# Formula needed to reference the same cell in the last worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out a formula to reference the information in the same cell of the last worksheet. The formula is for a summary sheet at the beginning of the workbook, referencing the same cell of the last worksheet in the workbook no matter the name of the worksheet. A new sheet is created every month, updated with the information and changes from the previous month.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can try to provide a sample table or picture here.

Answer (score 0):

First we can suppose that name of each worksheet is the same as the name of the month of the data in that sheet.
For example: First sheet name is January, second sheet is February and so on.

We can also assume that there is a cell in each sheet contains a name of the month. Let's suppose that A1 is that cell.

To get the name of last worksheet we get the last month name based on A1 value using this formula

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1")-1, "MMMM")
```

We can get the reference for any cell by using this formula

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

So by combining these formulas with INDIRECT function we can get the value of the same cell in the last worksheet by this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1")-1, "MMMM")&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

Then, we can apply any calculation on that value of the last month.

Comment: What if the worksheets are not month based. The worksheets are all labeled "Pay Estimate 1" and so forth. How would your formula look then?

Comment: Suppose that every sheet has a cell contains the current number that in the woorksheet name. If A1 cell contains number 3 so the last work sheet name would be "Pay Estimate 2" in this case the formula would be as following:  

    =INDIRECT("'Pay Estimate "&A1-1&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the old macro function `GET.WORKBOOK`.
To do this you must define a name in the **Name Manager** e.g.
lastsh : `=INDEX(GET.WORKBOOK(1),COLUMNS(GET.WORKBOOK(1)))`
The name `lastsh` returns a name of a last sheet in the workbook.
Then you can use a formula in your sheet:
`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),,,lastsh))`
This formula is similar to that from the another answer.
The file must be saved in a format which enables using macros e.g. `.xlsm` or `.xls`.